# angular select box - ng-options custom description

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a working angular select box:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="selectedFeatureTypeFeature"
        ng-options="FeatureTypeFeature.ProjectVersionFeatureID as
        FeatureTypeFeature.Description for FeatureTypeFeature in FeatureTypeFeatures"></select>
```

Which I'm trying to modify the 'as' portion in the ng-options, to look like this:

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="selectedFeatureTypeFeature"
        ng-options="FeatureTypeFeature.ProjectVersionFeatureID as
        (FeatureTypeFeature.CustomDesciption != null? FeatureTypeFeature.CustomDescription : FeatureTypeFeature.Description) for FeatureTypeFeature in FeatureTypeFeatures"></select>
```

The difference is some FeatureTypeFeatures have a custom description and some do not. I want to display the custom description when its available, and the normal description when its not.

The problem is - it will only display the regular description whether there is custom description or not.

Answer (score 0):

Logic like this really belongs in the controller, rather than the view. 
An easy way to create a conditional list is to use the `angular.forEach` function in your controller. Here are the [docs.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

Without knowing the context of how your data is structured and your existing controller, I've created a generic solution which you can look through here: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rKlz5WyfvsWNnPkwtqj2?p=preview).

Basically you create a new `$scope` variable for the descriptions (and the id's) using the `forEach` iterator to conditionally `push` the `description` if the `customDescription` is empty:

```
  $scope.descriptionList = [];

  angular.forEach($scope.FeatureType, function(value, key) {
    if (value.customDescription !== '')
      $scope.descriptionList.push({ id:value.id, description:value.customDescription});
    else
      $scope.descriptionList.push({ id:value.id, description:value.description});
  });
```

Then use this new `$scope` variable to populate your `<select>` form.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help. I ended up having to create a function, calling it for each iteration. I'll post the solution

Answer (score 0):

Solution: created a function in the controller, which returned the correct Description.

Html:

```
ng-options="FeatureTypeFeature.ProjectVersionFeatureID as (getFeatureTypeFeatureDescription(FeatureTypeFeature)) for FeatureTypeFeature in FeatureTypeFeatures"
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.getFeatureTypeFeatureDescription = function (featureTypeFeature) {
    return featureTypeFeature.CustomDescription || featureTypeFeature.Description;
}
```